# Push notifications - getting the intent information when notification clicked, app running

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I have implemented Firebase push notifications and when the app is in the foreground, I create a custom notification using Pending Intent. When the notification is clicked it opens a 
new activity. If the app is open and activity running I dont want to recreate it but just open it.
I have set the launchMode to 'singleTask' which does the trick.

The problem with this is I am passing extras with the Intent and onCreate does not get called and directly fires the onResume.

how can i get the extras.

Am i doing anything wrong here. your help and suggestions will be very helpful

here is the code to create custom notification Pending intent.

```
private void sendNotification(PushNotification pushNotification) {
        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BottomNavigationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pushNotification", (Serializable) pushNotification);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,(int) System.currentTimeMillis() /* request code */, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500};

            Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(pushNotification.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(pushNotification.getMessage())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(pattern)
                    .setLights(Color.BLUE,1,1)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify( (int) System.currentTimeMillis() /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.BottomNavigationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
        </activity>
```

BottomNavigationActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            PushNotification pushNotification = (PushNotification) intent.getSerializableExtra("pushNotification");
            if(null != intent.getExtras()){
                //here i get the pushnotification data and do something with it.
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    }
```

Thanks
R

Comment: Override `onNewIntent()`. As the launch mode is _singleTask_, the intent will be passed to `onNewIntent()` if the activity is in foreground.

Comment: I did override this function and should i write anything in it. just overriding it did not do any difference and onCreate was not called

Comment: Handle the received intent here(in `onNewIntent()`).

Comment: okay thank you, trying that now.

Comment: that did work for me. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to use the Broadcast receiver.

When you receive the push from firebase in firebase service send the local broadcast to your required activity. For that check, first app is running or not.

Example:

In your FCM MessagingService place this method to check that app is running or not

```
 private boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (am != null && am.getRunningAppProcesses() !=null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```

in onReceive method into FirebaseMessagingService

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


       if (isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {

           // send broadcast

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            Intent i = new Intent("broadCastName");
            // Data you need to pass to activity
            i.putExtra("message","messageData"); 
            context.sendBroadcast(i);

       } else  {
         // send extra with intent and start activity
           Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("message","messageData");
           startActivity(intent)

          /* or here you can also broadcast with data and one flag bit 
            then into your activity when you received this flag bit start that activity again from itself.
          */ 
       }


}
```

Add this inside your activity class

```
  BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver =  new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        String message = b.getString("message");

        Log.e("newmesage", "" + message);
       // here you will get your extra data. Use that as required and handle.
    }
};
```